# When I use axios.post with express, CORS error occur

Tags: node.js, express, axios

When I set data in axios.post, CORS error occurs. If I set axios.post without param data, it works. Same for axios.get(), no CORS error

JS code

```
      btn.onclick = function () {
        axios({
            method:'post',
            url:'http://localhost:3000/wrong',
            data:{
              user:'Joe',
              age:10
            }
        }).then(response=>{
            console.log(response);
        });
      };
```

nodeJS code

```
let express=require('express');

let app=express();
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/wrong',(req,res)=>{
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader("Aceess-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    res.setHeader("Aceess-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
    const r=JSON.stringify(req.body);
    res.send(r);
});
app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log('3000 listening...');
});
```

Comment: I use postman to send request in JSON, backend is OK, I dont know why -_-! axios.post default send JSON, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `cors` in your Backend to let it accept requests coming from other origins.

Run this command to install the package:

```
npm i --save-dev cors
```

and use it on your express app this way

```
const cors = require('cors')
// ...
app.use(cors())
```

This will allow any request to be handled

Comment: Cors is not in this usage a devDependency

Comment: I use postman to send request in JSON, backend is OK, I dont know why  -_-!      axios.post default send JSON, right?